# Grammar- Estar or Ser robado?

Tags: gramática, verbos

If you want to say " Last week three bikes were stolen in my school", would you say " la semana pasada tres bicicletas fueron robadas en mi colegio" or "...estuvieron robadas en mi colegio"? Or could you say something else using "se" or "nos"?
Thank you

Comment: The periphrastic passive voice in Spanish (the one that works like the one in English) always uses *ser*, not *estar*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to peppermint-frappé's answer, one can also say:

- La semana pasada se robaron tres bicicletas en mi colegio
- La semana pasada nos robaron tres bicicletas en mi colegio
- La semana pasada fueron robadas tres bicicletas en mi colegio (compare with the 2nd answer of his answer, this word order makes it sound perfectly native)
- La semana pasada nos fueron robadas tres bicicletas en mi colegio

Answer (score 3):

IMHO:

- "La semana pasada robaron tres bicicletas en mi colegio" is more natural
- "La semana pasada tres bicicletas fueron robadas en mi colegio" is correct but a little awkward.
- "La semana pasada tres bicicletas estuvieron robadas en mi colegio" is not correct.